# Get String between to string preg_match

Tags: php, regex

i have this preg_match in php to get the url string between to string. but my problem is i can't get any data out of it

```
preg_match( "/\[(gmap)\](.*?)\[\/(gmap)\]/si", $content, $url)
```

i need to get the string inside of this string

```
[gmap]http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=325x125&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:purple|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false[/gmap]
```

but i can't get a result. why?

```
$url[2]
```

i need to have

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=325x125&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:purple|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Works as expected, `$url[2]` is the string between `[gmap]` and `[/gmap]`.

Comment: The code works as expected. See http://ideone.com/DJTRaE

Comment: i see.ill examine my code again. if i had done something wrong. thankjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly fine :

```
<?php
  $url="";
   $content = '[gmap]http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=325x125&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:purple|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false[/gmap]';
    preg_match( "/\[(gmap)\](.*?)\[\/(gmap)\]/si", $content, $url);
    print  $url[2];

    ?>
```

Cheers!

Comment: How is it different from OP?

Comment: person was not using echo/print to get the string .. so to guide him in the right direction , i just pasted the whole working code

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you got an issue because the `.*` also includes the [ character.
You could use this instead :

```
preg_match("/\[(gmap)\]([^\[]*)?\[\/(gmap)\]/si", $content, $url);
```

Comment: Because he tacked the question mark to the dot asterisk, it should not include the opening square brace.  It should grab everything `.*` up until it hits the next part of the expression `?`, which in this case is an opening square brace.